# What does this mean in sql? ... WHERE T1.x = T2.y

Tags: sql, ms-access

I found this in someones code and it does not compare columns as it looks like, so i wonder what does it acctually compare? Is it all rows from T1 that are included in T2? Or does it compare current comparing value of T1 with current comparing value of T2? Or something else? Database used is Access

full example:

SELECT T1.id , T2.user_id FROM table1 T1, table2 T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.user_id

Comment: Really, you should learn a bit about SQL if you are going to be reading the code.  That compares the value of `x` in `t1` to `y` in `t2`.

Comment: You want to say that it compares those 2 collumns? I thought that too, but in the code i run it didn't work like that.

Comment: You see `table1 T1`? That means, "for this query, make `T1` an alias for table1, same with T2. And that again means, you compare `id` from table1 with `user_id` from table2

Comment: By value you mean collum or?

Comment: This is essentially an alternative way to write
`SELECT T1.id , T2.user_id FROM table1 T1 join table2 T2 on T1.id = T2.user_id`

Comment: @YossiVainshtein does that work like INNER JOIN ?

Comment: @Warix3  Yes. `T1.id = T2.user_id` would be equivalent to a regular, INNER JOIN. 
In Oracle (and maybe others) you can even make a LEFT OUTER JOIN in this style, like this `T1.id (+) = T2.user_id`, But I think it's considered bad style.

Comment: Ok , thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @YossiVainshtein but what if i have code like this:
'SELECT T1.id , T2.user_id, T3.name FROM table1 T1, table2 T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.user_id AND T1.name = T3.name' How will that translate?

Comment: @Warix3 Similarly to the 2 tables case, this will join the 3 tables, as if you specified the filters in JOIN...ON part. Essintially this will be equivalent to `SELECT T1.id, T2.user_id, T3.name FROM table1 T1 INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.user_id INNER JOIN  table3 T3 ON T1.name = T3.name`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have 6 'A's in the ID field of table1 and 4 'A's in user_id from Table2 you will have 24 pairs of 'A's in the output.  (that is if the person didn't know what an ID field was of course.  ID's are supposed to be Unique.)

Oh and stop using Access.  You might like it to learn SQL but you can't do much of anything with it when you start your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I personally don't use Access, but the project i work on uses it.

Comment: Nothing what mentioned about "the project". Access is a powerful for many tasks but, of course, not for everything.